# Show Windows Form when Datagridview is completely loaded

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Windows Form with 2 DataGridViews... Both GridViews are connected to a Database ..

Because it need some time to load the data ... I want to show the Form when the data is completely loaded..

I load my DataGridViews in the Form1_load-function:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadSettings();

        try
        {
            LoadData(); // This line loads the Views
            setSettings();
            CloseConnection();

            dataGridView1.Select();
            dataGridView2.Select();
        }
        catch (Exception eFormLoad)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(eFormLoad.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Do I need I splash Screen? What is the correct order to load the data?

Comment: This depends on what you want the user to see while you're loading data.  If you don't want them to see anything, you can do this in the form initialization method or in the main method that calls the form.  I would recommend a splash screen though.

Comment: Is there a problem with what you have?  How does it not do what you want?  A Splash Screen is going to be subjective/opinion based.  All your posts have a negative score, so you may want to read [ask] and take the [tour] because the site will not let you keep doing that.  Also tag spam is never a good idea

Comment: Users are impatient. In my experience, if they launch your app and see nothing while you fill two datagridviews with lots of data, they're going to click on the program's icon another 500 times until they see your window. For that reason, I think it's a good idea to use a splash screen.

Comment: Normally you would have the DGV DataSource = DataTable and the DataTable you will load changes using a DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable).  The DGV doesn't get updated until you set the  DGV.DataSource = null and then back to the DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

**VB.Net**

```
Public Sub New()
InitializeComponent()
LoadData
End Sub
```

**C#**

```
public Form1()
{
LoadData
}
```

But as @oppassum stated in the comments , it depends on what you want the user to see while you're loading data. (but you should follow @Plutonix's advice and consider taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))